# VS Code: What is the step called when you double click a tab to un-italicize the label and what is the keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

You click a file in the file tree. It is opened, but the title of the tab is italicized. You double click the tab to un-italicize the tab because if you didn't and you click a different file in the tree, the italicized tab will be replaced. What is the keyboard shortcut to change the current (presumably italicized) tab to non-italicized as if you had double clicked on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The according command is called `View: Keep Editor` and its default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: keep editor command]

You can also access this function via right click on the editor tab, there it is called "Keep open".

[image: keep open menu entry]

Comment: cool didn't know you could right click tabs

Answer (score 2):

Ah - I came here seeking the significance of the italicisation (so now I know) - but had already noticed that it reverted if I saved (so Ctrl+S is another way to get there)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33577791)

Comment: idc it's still helpful to the post